# Android: Programmatically adding TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am trying to add a TextInputLayout with an EditText to a LinearLayout programmatically. My approach:

```java
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox));
textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.Base_Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_TextInputLayout);

TextInputEditText editText = new TextInputEditText(getContext());
editText.setHint("test");

textInputLayout.addView(editText, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.addView(textInputLayout);
```

However, the result looks extremly buggy:

[image: buggy view]

---

Weirdly enough, adding the same TextInputLayout via XML works:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="kommentar"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.TextInputLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: working view via xml]

---

Now, I need to add that the programmatical approach worked before upgrading to *Material 1.1*. I am using material components only. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to do it programatically? It makes view-layer logic more complicated, one should avoid adding/removing views programatically. I would keep this text input layout initially in XML, but change visibility from GONE to VISIBLE when it is needed, or swap fragments and etc.

Comment: Like @Steyrix wrote, set the visibility attribute to invisible in xml, then change it within code with .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I am well aware of the fact that one should not create UI components via Java, however, in this case it's required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the style attribute you have to use `setBoxBackgroundMode()` method to use **OutlineBox** style. Beside this, you should have use `TextInputLayout`'s `context` to create `TextInputEditText`. Check below:

```
textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.white));
textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE);

//Must use context of textInputLayout
TextInputEditText editText = new TextInputEditText(textInputLayout.getContext());
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! The line ```new TextInputEditText(textInputLayout.getContext());``` is the answer in my case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please add the full code for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to achieve the same thing and when I was about to give up I found [this Material Components GitHub issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1183). Quoting *gabrielemariotti*'s answer below, which is for a **MaterialButton**, but the same applies to **TextInputLayout**, and probably other Material Components.

If you want to create a custom button with a **custom style** you have to:

- define an attribute in attrs.xml
  `<attr name="myButtonStyle" format="reference"/>`
- assign in your app theme a value to this new attr:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="myButtonStyle">@style/AccentButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
```

with:

```
    <style name="AccentButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/....</item>
        <item name="iconTint">@color/....</item>
    </style>
```

and then use this constructor:

```kotlin
class AccentButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.myButtonStyle
  ) : MaterialButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same issue. the accepted answer was still not rendering the layout correctly
I then saw the following snippet in the docs... lol

**Using text fields programmatically**

If you construct the TextInputEditText child of a TextInputLayout programmatically, you should use TextInputLayout's context to create the view. This will allow TextInputLayout to pass along the appropriate styling to the edit text.

```
val textInputLayout = TextInputLayout(context)
val editText = TextInputEditText(textInputLayout.context)
```

sources:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md